# QWebView подмена document.referrer

Tags: qt

Каким образом можно установить свой document.referrer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса `QWebFrame` имеется перегруженный метод:

```
void load(const QNetworkRequest &req
    , QNetworkAccessManager::Operation operation
        = QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation
    , const QByteArray &body = QByteArray())
```

... который позволяет отправлять произвольные запросы через `QNetworkAccessManager`.

Чтобы создать запрос с http-заголовком на ссылающуюся страницу (referrer), можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl("http://google.ru");
request.setRawHeader("Referer", "http://mysite.ru");
```

Таким же образом в запрос можно добавить и иные, подчас необходимые, http-заголовки:

```
request.setRawHeader("Accept"
    , "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8,*;q=0.5");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language"
    , "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
request.setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "My mega browser v 1.0");
```

Отправка вновь созданного запроса:

```
QWebView *view = ...;
view->page()->mainFrame()->load(request);
```

Иногда неудобно всякий раз создавать собственный `QNetworkRequest`, который может не сильно отличаться от запроса к запросу, так как приводит к копированию практически одинакового участка кода, но "разбросанного" в различных модулях одного проекта.

В этом случае можно унаследовать `QNetworkAccessManager` и переопределить его защищённый (protected) метод:

```
QNetworkReply *createRequest(Operation op
    , const QNetworkRequest &req
    , QIODevice *outgoingData = 0)
```

Например, так:

```
QNetworkReply *MyNetworkManager::createRequest(Operation op
    , const QNetworkRequest &req
    , QIODevice *outgoingData) {

    QNetworkRequest request(req);
    request.setRawHeader("Referer", "http://mysite.ru");

    return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op
        , request, outgoingData);
}
```

Теперь любой запрос, который будет отправлен через произвольный `MyNetworkManager`, будет содержать http-заголовок на ссылающуюся страницу.

Остаётся установить объект `MyNetworkManager` в `QWebPage`, чтобы всё это хозяйство заработало:

```
QWebView *view = ...;
MyNetworkManager *mngr = ...;
view->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(mngr);
```

Следует отметить, что установка произвольного менеджера соединений должна производиться до выполнения `QWebPage` первого запроса.